# Best way to replace a text using CSS

Tags: css

I would like to replace a text say 'company name' in my project. The use-case is to produce documents (after pre-processing) for different companies only by maintaining a different stylesheet for different company.

SEO not much of the importance here.

I am using this approach:

**html**

```
<span class="company-name"> YourCompanyName </span>​
```

**css**

```
.company-name{font-size: 0}

.company-name:after{
      content: "New Company Name";
      font-size: 14px;
 }​
```

and here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cN9gZ/

so here is my quick question: **Is there any better way of doing the same thing, using css only?**

Comment: I'd rather use jQuery or PHP to replace it, but using CSS only that seems like a pretty good way to do it aside from older internet browsers.

Comment: Relying on the stylesheet to replace content is generally a bad idea.

Comment: yes that's the purpose. I would be pre-processing my html to produce the documents. I'll make this point clear in my question.

Comment: agreed... but i don't want to keep duplicate copy of **content**. It's similar to creating a template, where only style and minor text get changed for different situation.

Comment: I understand that you're using this to create PDF documents, don't care about SEO, etc., which is fine and everything, but why are you asking for a "better" solution when this seems to already do exactly what you want? Are you having a problem? If so, what is the problem? Of course, you'd be better of using a server side solution to change the actual markup for all cases...

Comment: You might achieve something like that with CSS background images (different stylesheets containing different company logo, for example; something similar to CSS sprites). However, it is really not what CSS is designed for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really need to do such things in CSS, the following is a little more logical and a little less risky (with the Usual CSS Caveats in mind):

```
<style>
.company-name:after{
  content: "New Company Name";
}​
</style>
<span class="company-name"></span>
```

That is, use an element with empty content, so you don’t need any trick to hide the dummy content.

Comment: +1.. ! I really like this idea, it makes more sense.!! but i'll wait for other to respond.

Comment: How can I include a new line? Tried <br> and \n without success. Thanks

Comment: @MariusAndreiana, that’s a different question, possibly one that has been asked and answered at SO before. But basically you would use `\a` in the content and `white-space: pre-wrap` on the pseudo-element.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any better way of doing the same thing, using css only?

No. Every other effect would basically result in the same method used: hide the original content and replace it with a pseudo-element (`::after` or `::before`).

Note that search engines are likely to ignore the stylesheet, which could result in some strange search results. It's almost always a better idea to replace fixed content in the markup instead. In almost all cases it will take only a simple find-and-replace. JavaScript and CSS can be deactivated - markup can't.

Comment: +1 for including search engine. but i don't think that's the use case here... the point to produce documents after preprocesing.. like .chm, pdf etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

CSS really isn't designed for this kind of thing. You'd be better off using Javascript, or even better, just altering the HTML code itself.

There really isn't any other way to do what you're asking in CSS other than the way you've done it: The `content` property isn't available in most CSS styles, because CSS isn't intended for placing content.